# How to count if value = one of multiple values?

Tags: formula, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I'm trying to figure out how to countif a range = one of multiple values using LibreOffice / OpenOffice Calc.

So it would be where it counted if the value = one in a range of values (E.g B1:B20 contains all the values that would be acceptable for it to count one for).

I tried a few variations of countif and ors but still confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what are you asking, but it seems to me that you should add a column, where using the "if" function, add an "1" to the values that match whatever are you looking for. Then you just sum the "1" and you get the count.

For instance, lets say you are looking for the word "one". Then the if function should be: =IF(C7="one";1;0). C would be the column of the value to check. If the value match, then a "1" would appears. Remember to use "" if the value is text.